# Django TokenAuthentication - extending JWT obtain_jwt_token

Tags: django, django-rest-framework-jwt

I have a Django REST app and token authentication powered by [Django REST framework JWT Auth](https://getblimp.github.io/django-rest-framework-jwt/)

Let me formulate my high-level goal:

My goal is to generate a token for the user if he provides correct credentials AND THEN immediately after successful login I want to perform some additional set of operations. For simplicity, let's say I want to print "Hello" to the console.

Right now my code looks like this:

```
from rest_framework_jwt.views import obtain_jwt_token

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^api-token-auth/', obtain_jwt_token),
]
```

What I want to do is the following

1. Get the token that `obtain_jwt_token` generates
2. If authentication was successful, do some additional operations and return the token to the user.

I feel lost in the jungles of all this Django architecture related to authentication classes. Do I understand correctly that if I am using third-party packages like Django JWT, I have no power on login process and there's no way to perform additional operations after the user logs in? And if I want to have more power on login process, I have to do all the job that Django JWT developers have done from scratch? Can I somehow add some operations **ON TOP** of Django JWT's `obtain_jwt_token` ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`obtain_jwt_token`](https://github.com/GetBlimp/django-rest-framework-jwt/blob/master/rest_framework_jwt/views.py#L94) is just a reference to a view, and as with any view you can just subclass it and reference that instead

```
class MySpecialJWT(ObtainJSONWebToken):
    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        response = super().post(request, *args, **kwargs)
        # foo bar
        return response
```

Comment: @EdgarNavasardyan - Their `JSONWebTokenAPIView` still uses a [`post`](https://github.com/GetBlimp/django-rest-framework-jwt/blob/master/rest_framework_jwt/views.py#L53) method so simply just call super to allow them to do their thing, then expand as required

Comment: You made my day